# Postgresql not working showing fatal error

Tags: python, django, pgadmin

I am trying to work with Postgresql as my database for website that i am making in django. However, the postgresql and the pg-admin tool is installing without any eror I am unable to open the database. First i thought it was compatibility issue as I my os is windows 7 ultimate bbut then i  tried to install all the previous versions of the database and it still doesn't open.

The error i am getting is:

```
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe -s C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
  - APPDATA: C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Roaming
  - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin
  - CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \\.\pipe\crashpad_3400_DAGOSZHYAFRGHRAW
  - CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Whoa! NW.js has crashed. Relaunch now?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
  - CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
  - CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - COMPUTERNAME: INTEL-PC
  - ComSpec: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
  - FP_NO_HOST_CHECK: NO
  - HOMEDRIVE: C:
  - HOMEPATH: \Users\Intel
  - JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1
  - JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin\server\jvm.dll: PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin
  - LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Local
  - LOGONSERVER: \\INTEL-PC
  - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 2
  - OS: Windows_NT
  - Path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin;C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37;C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1.2\bin;;F:\Microsoft VS Code\bin
  - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: ce0fb81d-5e4a-48d7-8976-49a0e405e06d
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 49340
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
  - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  - PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel
  - PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
  - PROCESSOR_REVISION: 0f0d
  - ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
  - ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
  - ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
  - ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
  - PSModulePath: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
  - PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
  - PyCharm: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1.2\bin;
  - SESSIONNAME: Console
  - SystemDrive: C:
  - SystemRoot: C:\Windows
  - TEMP: C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Local\Temp
  - TMP: C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Local\Temp
  - USERDOMAIN: Intel-PC
  - USERNAME: Intel
  - USERPROFILE: C:\Users\Intel
  - windir: C:\Windows
  - windows_tracing_flags: 3
  - windows_tracing_logfile: C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log
--------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cheroot.wsgi import Server as CherootServer
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\cheroot\wsgi.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import server
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\cheroot\server.py", line 70, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "email\utils.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "socket.py", line 49, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _socket: The parameter is incorrect.
```

What should i do??

Comment: This could happen if  you have a 32-bit version of PostgreSQL but a 64-bit version of Python. I would check that first.

Comment: I have checked sir,both of my python and postgresql are 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same issue by installing Microsoft security update KB3063858 which includes KB2533623 on my win 2008R2 SP1 and reinstalling pgAdmin after that.
The same update is available for Win 7 on Microsoft site.